# Tomcat 7 Jersey REST not working

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I have followed numerous examples and tutorials trying to get my REST web service running but without any success. I'm using IntelliJ 13, Maven3, Java 7 and Tomcat 7.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jafwatt</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>rest</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jafwatt.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

CustomerResource.java

```
package com.jafwatt.rest;

import com.jafwatt.rest.entity.Customer;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    private Map<Integer, Customer> customerDB = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Customer>();
    private AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getCustomers() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response createCustomer(InputStream is) {
        Customer customer = readCustomer(is);
        customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
        customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);
        System.out.println("Created customer " + customer.getId());
        return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/"
                + customer.getId())).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public StreamingOutput getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        final Customer customer = customerDB.get(id);
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(
                    Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(OutputStream outputStream)
                    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                outputCustomer(outputStream, customer);
            }

            private void outputCustomer(OutputStream outputStream, Customer customer) {

            }
        };
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id,
                               InputStream is) {
        Customer update = readCustomer(is);
        Customer current = customerDB.get(id);
        if (current == null)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        current.setFirstName(update.getFirstName());
        current.setLastName(update.getLastName());
        current.setStreet(update.getStreet());
        current.setState(update.getState());
        current.setZip(update.getZip());
        current.setCountry(update.getCountry());
    }

    private Customer readCustomer(InputStream is) {
        return new Customer();
    }
}
```

Maven builds the WAR without errors and Tomcat deploys the WAR without errors but no combination of URLs gets anything other than a 404 response.

The root context is 'rest' and the URLs I have tried:

```
http://localhost:8090/rest
http://localhost:8090/rest/custsomers
http://localhost:8090/rest/custsomers/hello
```

I know Tomcat is running on that port because I can access the manager app.

I have read so many posts on Stackoverflow and elsewhere and I'm really frustrated that what should be a relatively simple task is beyond me.

Please help.

Comment: What happens when u invoke the API ? is it 404 ?

Comment: Please add the exact error messages to your question; also include a sample request URL so we can see how you're calling your service.

Comment: I realised on the drive home that I missed off that little detail. Edited to explain I'm getting 404s.

Comment: Please post the exact url you are using. I'm guessing its the fact you are hitting the wrong port number. but its just a guess.

Comment: @user1493954 I have edited my OP with the URLs but it's not a port number issue. I can reach the Tomcat server, just not my web services.

Comment: Your artifactid is `rest-service`, is this the exact WAR file you're deploying?  Whats in your webapps folder?

Comment: @JohnAment The WAR file is called 'rest.war' and Tomcat's manager app shows 'rest' as a root context.

Comment: Do you see any console logs? You have a typo in your URL - not sure if that's the real problem `http://localhost:8090/rest/customers/hello` might work, but stack traces from your server would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my dependencies.

This is how they look now my web service is working:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

---

on intellij project settings make sure that under modules the Facet 'Web' - Web resource directory is setup correctly. [image: web resource directory setup]